# How to get multiple views (html) using XSLT on 1 XML file

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have 1 big XML file with all data I need.

What I need is something like this:
1 page = Overview. on this page a table is shown. Each row starts with a hyperlink to a detail page.

I am looking for a way to do it with XML, XSLT and HTML only. No server side processing.

Any way to achieve this?

Right now the XML has the XSLT to use for the overview specified in the header:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="overview.xslt"?>
```

If I cannot do it with multiple XSLT files, is there a way to read the querystring from the url in XSLT?

Comment: Your generated html page for overview should have href to details page that will include the 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="details.xslt"?>

Comment: I just use XML + XSLT. No actual html files are generated

Comment: The generated HTML markup should have a hyperlink to an XML file that references the details.xslt transform.

Comment: I only have 1 XML file containing all data needed

Comment: If there's no possibility of serving up the XML dynamically with the needed `<?xsl-stylesheet ?>` inserted, perhaps the next best option is to have the XSLT output all of the HTML for everything, with most of it initially hidden, and then use JavaScript to show or hide it as needed. Of course, depending on the size of the XML file, this could produce a lot of HTML, so there would be limits to how much would be realistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Let the XSLT create one big HTML and hide all the sections except the one that you'd like to show.
2. Use JavaScript to initiate different transforms, replacing the body of the current HTML with the body of the HTML that was returned by the transformation. You could either use one stylesheet that takes a different route depending on the value of a `<xsl:parameter>` that needs to be supplied for every transform, or you use different stylesheets.

Let's assume you have the following XML (lets call it `text.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<myXml>
  <chapter id="c1">
    <heading>Heading 1</heading>
    <content>This is text of chapter one.</content>
  </chapter>
  <chapter id="c2">
    <heading>Heading 2</heading>
    <content>This is text of chapter two.</content>
  </chapter>
</myXml>
```

Then, for suggestion 1, you could do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function showView(id) {
            document.getElementById("dynamicStyle").innerHTML = "#" + id + "{display:inline}";
          }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
          .view {display:none};
        </style>
        <style type="text/css" id="dynamicStyle">
          #overview{display:inline}
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="view overview" id="overview">
          <h1>Overview</h1>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="myXml/chapter" mode="overview"/>
        </div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="myXml/chapter" mode="detail"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="chapter" mode="overview">
    <div><a href="javascript:showView('{@id}')"><xsl:value-of select="heading"/></a></div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="chapter" mode="detail">
    <div class="view detail" id="{@id}">
      <div><a href="javascript:showView('overview')">Back to overview</a></div>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="detail"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="heading" mode="detail">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content" mode="detail">
    <div><xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key is creating separate divs for each view and toggling between them by letting JavaScript change the CSS.

Method 2 might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:param name="view" select="'overview'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function showView(id) {
            document.documentElement.replaceChild(transform(id).body, document.body);
          }
          function loadXML(fileName,mime) {
            var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttpRequest.open("GET",fileName,false);
            if(mime) xmlHttpRequest.overrideMimeType(mime);
            xmlHttpRequest.send("");
            return xmlHttpRequest.responseXML;
          }
          function transform(view) {
            var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
            xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(loadXML('test.xsl','application/xslt+xml'));
            xsltProcessor.setParameter(null,'view',view);
            return xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(loadXML('test.xml'),document);
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$view = 'overview'">
            <div>
              <h1>Overview</h1>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="myXml/chapter" mode="overview"/>
            </div>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="myXml/chapter[@id = $view]" mode="detail"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="chapter" mode="overview">
    <div><a href="javascript:showView('{@id}')"><xsl:value-of select="heading"/></a></div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="chapter" mode="detail">
    <div>
      <div><a href="javascript:showView('overview')">Back to overview</a></div>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="detail"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="heading" mode="detail">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content" mode="detail">
    <div><xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key here is loading the stylesheet and the XML using JavaScript and using the JavaScript object `XSLTProcessor` to do a transform, then replace the body of the document. In this example, I use one stylesheet with different parameters, but you could also load different stylesheet. You'd have to adjust the `transform()` function accordingly, replacing `test.xsl` with a variable that needs to be supplied somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. conclusion for now is I do have to generate all the seperate html files. 2 reasons: 1. The resulting html file would be way too large over time. 2. seems XML + XSLT in a browser is not supported by iphone web browser (at least I couldn't get it to work).

Comment: Are you sure about the iPhone? I don't have any iOS devices at hand, but a while ago I successfully ran an application that used something along the lines of my method 2 on an iPad.

Comment: method 2 might work, what didn't work is simple xml with Xslt reference in it.
Just tested it on an iPad in safari and there it did work. Strange!